# How do i scrape a structured table from a webpage using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nested-lists

I have the following codes to scrape a website (https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels/STENAWECO-ENERGY-IMO-9683984-MMSI-538005270). As there are similar class names, it is difficult to pinpoint the table class names to scrape data to CSV file. How do i ensure that i am scraping the correct information?

**My codes are**

```
agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'} 
urlFile = requests.get('https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels/STENAWECO-ENERGY-IMO-9683984-MMSI-538005270', headers = agent)

soupHtml = BeautifulSoup(urlFile.content, 'lxml')

rowsFind = soupHtml.find_all("table",{"class": "tparams"})
print(rowsFind)
for i in rowsFind:
    z = i.find_all("tr")
for r in z:
    cols = r.find_all('td' , 'v3')
    cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]
    print(cols)
    AISVessel.append(cols[0])

AIStable.append(AISVessel)
```

**Right now i have having this error:**

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

**The desired output will be:**

```
[['Tanker' , 'Marshall Islands' , 'USHOU > DOSPM' , 'Jan 3, 19:00' , '9683984 / 538005270' , '  V7CJ5', '183 / 32 m' ,  '11.4 m' ,' 115.4° / 13.5 kn ' , '19.60436 N/80.84751 W' , 'Jan 1, 2020 07:38 UTC']]
```

I want to append the relevant data as reflected above in a nested list to support writing it to CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To locate the right table, you can use CSS selector `h2:contains("AIS Data") ~ table.tparams td.v3` - this will get all `<td>` inside the table with header "AIS Data":

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

agent = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
urlFile = requests.get('https://www.vesselfinder.com/vessels/STENAWECO-ENERGY-IMO-9683984-MMSI-538005270', headers = agent)

soupHtml = BeautifulSoup(urlFile.content, 'lxml')

out = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in soupHtml.select('h2:contains("AIS Data") ~ table.tparams td.v3')]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['Tanker', 'Marshall Islands', 'USHOU > DOSPM', 'Jan 3, 19:00', '9683984 / 538005270', 'V7CJ5', '183 / 32 m', '11.4 m', '115.4° / 13.5 kn', '19.60436 N/80.84751 W', 'Jan 1, 2020 07:38 UTC']
```